# TikZ: Bottom right align text in rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am making some graphical models with tikz, and I have added a rectangle (plate./style) around three nodes. As you can see in the picture the text "N" is vertically/horizontally center aligned. I want to align the text "N" to the bottom right of the "plate" i.e. I want "N" at the bottom right corner of the rounded rectangle. Since I will be doing this repeatedly, I want this setting to be made inside tikzset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
  latentnode/.style={draw, minimum width=5mm, shape=circle, ultra thick, black},
  dagconn/.style={arrows=->, black, thick},
  plate/.style={draw, shape=rectangle, rounded corners=0.5ex, thick,
    minimum width=3.1cm, text width=3.1cm, align=right, inner sep=10pt, innerysep=10pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
   \node[latentnode] (1) [label=below left:$z_1$] at (1,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (2) [label=below left:$z_2$] at (2.5,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (3) [label=below left:$z_3$] at (4,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x1) [label=left:$x_1$] at (1,1.5) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x2) [label=left:$x_2$] at (2.5,1.5) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x3) [label=left:$x_3$] at (4,1.5) {};
   \node[plate, inner sep=20pt, fit=(1) (2) (3)] (plate1) {N};

   \draw[dagconn] (1) to (2);
   \draw[dagconn] (2) to (3);
   \draw[dagconn] (1) to (x1);
   \draw[dagconn] (2) to (x2);
   \draw[dagconn] (3) to (x3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an argument for the `plate` style and use it to place the label using the `south.east` anchor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
  latentnode/.style={draw, minimum width=5mm, shape=circle, ultra thick, black},
  dagconn/.style={arrows=->, black, thick},
  plate/.style={draw, shape=rectangle, rounded corners=0.5ex, thick,
    minimum width=3.1cm, text width=3.1cm, align=right, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt,label={[xshift=-14pt,yshift=14pt]south east:#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
   \node[latentnode] (1) [label=below left:$z_1$] at (1,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (2) [label=below left:$z_2$] at (2.5,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (3) [label=below left:$z_3$] at (4,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x1) [label=left:$x_1$] at (1,1.5) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x2) [label=left:$x_2$] at (2.5,1.5) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x3) [label=left:$x_3$] at (4,1.5) {};
   \node[plate=N, inner sep=20pt, fit=(1) (2) (3)] (plate1) {};

   \draw[dagconn] (1) to (2);
   \draw[dagconn] (2) to (3);
   \draw[dagconn] (1) to (x1);
   \draw[dagconn] (2) to (x2);
   \draw[dagconn] (3) to (x3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This solution is similar to Gonzalo's answer but instead of `label` uses `append after command` option to place the node. It also uses `positioning` library although it's not strictly necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\tikzset{
  latentnode/.style={draw, minimum width=5mm, shape=circle, ultra thick, black},
  dagconn/.style={arrows=->, black, thick},
  plate/.style={draw, shape=rectangle, rounded corners=0.5ex, thick,
    minimum width=3.1cm, text width=3.1cm, align=right, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt, 
    append after command={node[above left= 3pt of \tikzlastnode.south east] {#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
   \node[latentnode] (1) [label=below left:$z_1$] at (1,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (2) [label=below left:$z_2$] at (2.5,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (3) [label=below left:$z_3$] at (4,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x1) [label=left:$x_1$] at (1,1.5) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x2) [label=left:$x_2$] at (2.5,1.5) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x3) [label=left:$x_3$] at (4,1.5) {};
   \node[plate=N, inner sep=20pt, fit=(1) (2) (3)] (plate1) {};

   \draw[dagconn] (1) to (2);
   \draw[dagconn] (2) to (3);
   \draw[dagconn] (1) to (x1);
   \draw[dagconn] (2) to (x2);
   \draw[dagconn] (3) to (x3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this qualify as "inside tikz"?  I introduce a macro `\shft{}` that takes its argument and moves it down 43pt (actually 43pt plus its own height) and over 112pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\shft#1{\stackunder[43pt]{}{\kern112pt #1}}
\tikzset{
  latentnode/.style={draw, minimum width=5mm, shape=circle, ultra thick, black},
  dagconn/.style={arrows=->, black, thick},
  plate/.style={draw, shape=rectangle, rounded corners=0.5ex, thick,
    minimum width=3.1cm, text width=3.1cm, align=right, inner sep=10pt, %innerysep=10pt
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
   \node[latentnode] (1) [label=below left:$z_1$] at (1,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (2) [label=below left:$z_2$] at (2.5,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (3) [label=below left:$z_3$] at (4,3) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x1) [label=left:$x_1$] at (1,1.5) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x2) [label=left:$x_2$] at (2.5,1.5) {};
   \node[latentnode] (x3) [label=left:$x_3$] at (4,1.5) {};
   \node[plate, inner sep=20pt, fit=(1) (2) (3)] (plate1) {\shft{N}};

   \draw[dagconn] (1) to (2);
   \draw[dagconn] (2) to (3);
   \draw[dagconn] (1) to (x1);
   \draw[dagconn] (2) to (x2);
   \draw[dagconn] (3) to (x3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks. Can we somehow move \shft{} inside tikzset?

Comment: @ahmadh I'm sorry, but I don't know enough about `tikz` to answer your follow-up query.  Best wishes.